# Reading a POST payload from a G-Wan C Script

Tags: c, servlets, g-wan

I understand that reading actual query string params is made easy with the `get_arg` function. However, I am not seeing anything in the examples or documentation that will let me read the POST payload. In my case, it's a JSON encoded string. Parsing the JSON is easy enough once I can actually address it.

Does anyone have an example that shows how to read the raw POST payload in C?

Comment: Hi I have several examples. Here is one of them: https://github.com/fatihky/gwan-color-thief

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by just walking argv[]. Turns out it's as easy as:

```
char *raw_payload = (char*)argv[0];
```

Comment: FYI, G-WAN has some [JSON APIs](http://gwan.com/api#json) that may help, now that you know where to reference the POST payload.  And the [entity.c](http://gwan.com/source/entity.c) example may also help a bit.

Comment: @Mike: the **get_arg** function fetches the query parameters of both GET and POST requests. G-WAN does it transparently for you. +1 for having answered your own question.

Comment: @Gil the only issue with get_arg is that as far as I can see, it can only get named parameters. I couldn't work out a way of using it to get an unnamed payload.

Comment: @Mike, you are right. Hence the **argv[]** alternative that we provided for the other cases (and some other scripting languages than C) and the direct ***entity   = (char*)get_env(argv, REQ_ENTITY);** method depicted in entity.c